# Drupal 7 theme function outputs word 'array'

Tags: drupal-7, themes, preprocessor

In my hook_preprocess_node function I am changing the links by themeing and adding a t() function to allow translation.
The problem is when I render out in my node I get the word "ARRAY" printed out, this is using either

```
<?php  print render($field_downloads); ?> or <?php  print $field_downloads); ?>
```

in my node.

Code in template.php

```
$list_of_paths = array();
foreach($field_downloads as $index => $data)
{

    $file_uri = $data['uri'];
    $file_path = file_create_url($file_uri);
    $list_of_paths[] = '<strong> &gt;&gt;'. t('DOWNLOAD'). '</strong> '.l(t($data['description']), $file_path);
}



$variables['field_downloads'] .= theme("item_list", array(
  'items' => $list_of_paths,
  'type' => 'ul',
  'attributes' => array('class' => 'downloads'),    
));
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is that code in template.php? It should be inside `hook_preprocess_node()`

Comment: If there's already a var called `field_downloads` why not call your var something else (e.g. `$variables['custom_downloads'] = theme("item_list", array(...`)? At the moment you're concatenating `$variables['field_downloads']` (which may be an array) with `theme("item_list"`, which will return a string. Then you can run `print $custom_downloads` in your template file

Comment: sounds like good advice, there is no need for it to have the same name other than I thought I was being "efficient"